# tkinter create a paste button

Tags: tkinter, textbox, paste

I am onto my first ever project on tkinter. I have no idea of how code works, but based on my successful experience on visual basic I try to create similar apps for linux environment. Here is my first challenge that I am facing. I have to create a button that pastes the copied text into the textbox given in a tkinter form. The code so far created is as follows. Can you help the function part of clicking and appending the text.

```
from tkinter import *

 root = Tk()
 root.geometry("600x400")
 root.title("NoteMaker1_v4")

 f1 = Frame(root, width="600", height="100")
 f1.pack(side=TOP)
 f2 = Frame(root, width="600", height="300")
 f2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

tb1 = Text(f2)
tb1.pack()


def paste():
   self.clipboard_clear()
   self.clipboard_append(text)
   tb1.text = self.selection_get(selection='CLIPBOARD')


 pbtn = Button(f1, text="PASTE", activebackground="green", activeforeground="red", bd="5", bg="powder blue",
          command="paste", fg="purple", font=('arial', 15, 'bold'))
  pbtn.pack()

 root.mainloop()
```

Hope to get some simple solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output currently? And I'm not sure what you want exactly? Do you want to copy the text into the clipboard? (then why is the button called paste?) Or do you want to copy the current clipboard into the textbox? (then why do clear the clipboard immediately in the `paste` function?)

Comment: I want to copy the contents of clipboard to the textbox as append text